# Queries forcing LIKE vs = for some odd reason

Tags: sqlite

Having an issue where my queries used to work fine with = as in `WHERE some_int_field = some_other_int_field`. When I do that now I get 0 results. However if I do a `WHERE some_int_field LIKE some_other_int_field` I get my results. I have checked the length of the fields for hidden characters/spaces and the length of the fields are correct. They are both integer fields. Thoughts? Two tables structure below:

```
CREATE TABLE "languages"(
"language_id" Integer,
"name" Text,
"english" Text,
"spanish" Text,
"portuguese" Text,
"french" Text );

-- Create index languagesIdx
CREATE INDEX "languagesIdx" ON "languages"( "name" );
BEGIN; 
-------------
CREATE TABLE "drop_downs"(
"mode_data" Integer,
"text_index" Integer,
"language_id" Integer );

-- Create index drop_downsIdx
CREATE INDEX "drop_downsIdx" ON "drop_downs"( "mode_data", "language_id" );
BEGIN;
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite uses [dynamic typing](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) and does not care about the declared type of the fields.

You have strings in your fields.

To check which rows have strings, use something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM drop_downs WHERE typeof(mode_data) = 'text'
```

To convert all values in a column into numbers, use something like this:

```
UPDATE drop_downs SET mode_data = CAST(mode_data AS integer)
```